# How to collect profiling info from Haskell service running in Kubernetes?

Tags: haskell, kubernetes, profiling

I have a microservice written in Haskell, the compiler is 8.8.3.
I built it with `--profile` option and ran it with `+RTS -p`. It is running about 30 minutes, there is `<my-service>.prof` file but it is empty (literally 0 bytes). Previously I did it on my local machine and I stop the service with CTRL-C and after the exit it produced `<my-service>.prof` file which was not empty.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. How to collect profiling information when a Haskell microservice runs under Kubernetes in the most correct way (to be able to read this .prof file)?
2. How to pass run time parameter to Haskell run-time where to save this .prof file (maybe some workaround if no such an option), for 8.8.3 - because I have feeling that the file may be big and I can hit disk space problem. Also I don't know how to flush/read/get this file while microservice is running. I suppose if I will be able to pass full path for this .prof file then I can save it somewhere else on some permanent volume, to "kill" the service with `INT` signal for example, and to get this .prof file from the volume.

What is the usual/convenient way to get this .prof file when the service runs in Kubernetes?

PS. I saw some relevant options in the documentation for newest versions, but I am with 8.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do live profiling with GHC is to use the eventlog. You can insert `Debug.Trace.traceEvent` into your code at the functions that you want to measure and then compile with `-eventlog` and run with `+RTS -l -ol <output-file-name> -RTS`. You can use [`ghc-events-analyze`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-events-analyze) to analyze and visualize the produced eventlog.

The official eventlog documentation for GHC 8.8.3 is [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#tracing).